# How to call Javascript function from activex or dll

Tags: c#, javascript, html, activex

I found the similar questions [how to call java script function from activex or dll in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2296492/1058346) but this is not provide me solution.than i continue my searching finally i got msdn link on this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171712.aspx

**To access DOM from a UserControl hosted in Internet Explorer**

Create your own custom derived class of the UserControl class. For more information, see How to: Author Composite Controls.

Place the following code inside of your Load event handler for your UserControl:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = null;

    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Site != null)
        {
            doc = (HtmlDocument)this.Site.GetService(typeof(HtmlDocument));
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I am still unable to get DOM object in my class.I have try to see what i get in this.Site so i put it on a messagebox

```
   MessageBox.Show(this.Site.ToString());
```

which shows me strange thing that is

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control+AxSourcingSite
```

please help me..